# SCNPhysicsShape(shapes:transforms:) creates MULTIPLE shapes?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

My goal is to create a *single* physics body out of several of SceneKit's `SCNBox` geometries.

My understanding is that when I pass an `SCNPhysicsShape(shapes:transforms:)` to an `SCNPhysicsBody(type:shape:)`, it should create a single physics body.

However, I end up with something that seems suspiciously like it's **not** a *single* physics body at all, but rather several *separate* physics bodies -- one for each shape I passed into `SCNPhysicsShape(shapes:transforms:)`.

When I turn on `scnView.debugOptions = .showPhysicsShapes`, I can clearly see red lines defining the separate bodies in question. On its own, this isn't very convincing evidence (it's conceivable that those lines could be shown for whatever reason while still being a single physics body).

But there's another piece of data, here: The project in which I'm encountering this issue features a small ball that rolls around the scene -- and when that ball rolls over the red lines in question, the ball bounces up into the air a bit. So, it's quite obvious that, whatever is actually going on, **there are edges where I would expect to see none**.

This behavior is clearly visible in the following GIF. In it, each colored block is a separate `SCNBox` geometry with its own physics body. Each block has the exact same `position.z`. The ball bounces considerably as it crosses the point where one geometry meets another.

[image]

Here's some code illustrating the issue. `parent` is an `SCNNode` that holds the child nodes, and is the node to which I assign the physics body. Please assume that all properties are defined; I'm omitting things that aren't terribly relevant.

```
let childShape1 = SCNBox(width: 6, height: 2, length: 6, chamferRadius: 0.0)
//Other child shapes defined here...

//Set up the positional translation relative to the child node's parent:
let translateMatrixShape1 = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(childShape1.position.x, childShape1.position.y, childShape1.position.z)
//Other child translations defined here...

let parentShape = SCNPhysicsShape(shapes: [childShape1, childShape2, childShape3, childShape4], transforms: [translateMatrixShape1, translateMatrixShape2, translateMatrixShape3, translateMatrixShape4])

parent.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.static, shape: parentShape)
```

Now, `parentShape` is four rectangular boxes arranged around a central point, creating a sort of picture-frame-shaped object.

The ball is an `SCNNode` with an `SCNSphere` geometry and a dynamic physics body.

**Question:** Does anyone have any idea what might be going on, here? Have I somehow misunderstood how this whole thing works, or is this a limitation of SceneKit?

Comment: I wasn't aware of `flatennedClone`. That looks really promising, based on the documentation for it. I'll give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can create one single PhysicsBody from several geometry objects by making a flattenendClone from out of your (i.Ex.) parent node. This new node will have one single geometry then. For the PhysicsBody you can then use the geometry element of the new node. In Addition I recoommend to use a concavePolyhedron for the static body type. (I hope I understood you correctly)

Comment: You did understand me, thank you. This strategy should absolutely work -- but it doesn't. At least, it doesn't "work" in the sense that the (supposedly) single physics body created *still* has the same sharp edges where there should be a smooth surface that make the ball bounce instead of roll. I am using `concavePolyhedron`. Other things I'm experimenting with include adjusting the geometry's `subdivisionLevel` and `edgeCreasesSource`, but I don't know if I'm on the right track or not. This is a weird behavior, in my opinion.

Comment: would it be possiböe to share me your project, so I can have a look at it?

Comment: I'll see if I can recreate this behavior in a fresh project, and I'll share that with you so you can see the problem. Thank you for your help, and I"ll let you know when I have the project ready to share. :)

Comment: Ok, I've created an Xcode project demonstrating the problem. Now, I just need to figure out how to share it publicly with you without sharing any sensitive information such as Bundle Identifier. In the meantime, feel free to look at the GIF I just added to the question. It illustrates the problem. Thanks!

Comment: you could send me a download link iEx google drive. you will find my email within my website. see my profile for more info

Comment: Ok, I sent a Google Drive link to the email address specified on your website. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: So, I just figured out that when I disable continuous collision detection by removing the ball's `physicsBody?.continuousCollisionDetectionThreshold`, the bouncing problem *nearly* disappears entirely -- even *without* using `flattenedClone` or another such consolidation strategy. That's good news -- except for the fact that my game has some tunneling issues when I disable continuous collision detection. So, I still welcome your input. Maybe there's another way?